# How to separate multiple leaves from a single texture?

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I am building a forest for a project I am working on but I seem to be running into a few snags. I built a tree model using the "Sampling Tree Gen" add-on and also using some assets from Megascans such as leaves and bark PBR textures. When I place the assets in the material node, it shows the leaves but does not separate them.

[image: Leaf Image]

So I am stuck. I am not sure if there some sort of plug-in I have to download or if I did not do something right but any help would be appreciated. [image: Leaf Nodes]